# PatchPasswordEncryption error during ranger-admin install

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to [install ranger-admin manually](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.2/bk_installing_manually_book/content/install-the-ranger-policy-administration-service.html).  When I run the `setup.sh` script, it fails trying to patch the database (the patch is `PatchPasswordEncryption`). I get the error `Cannot acquire a connection on the database`. I am trying to use Oracle database for ranger-admin setup. It creates the user, tablespace, schema etc. fine but fails during the patch as mentioned.

My version of ambari is 2.0.  Please let me know what other info is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Ranger > 0.5 all java patches are logged using log4j. Can you check the file `ranger_db_patch.log` in the Ranger Log dir and see if there are any errors in it?